# Question on compiling pgfplot/tikz figures through latex+dvips+ps2pdf

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, dvips, bounding-box

I have a lot of problems when compiling pgfplots/tikz figures through the latex+dvips+ps2pdf chain. I can successfully compile the same set of pgfplots/tikz figures through pdflatex. The reason that I need to compile through the latex+dvips+ps2pdf chain is because that some math symbols are not embedded in the pdf file generated by pdflatex.

My questions are as follows.

1. How can I include pdf figures using \includegraphics and compiling through the latex+dvips+ps2pdf chain?

If a solution exists for this option, then I can first compile the pgfplots/tikz figures into pdf output figures. Next, I can include the pdf figures using \includegraphics and compiling through the latex+dvips+ps2pdf chain.

2. The bounding box problem when compiling pgfplots/tikz figures through the latex+dvips+ps2pdf chain.

A MWE called `example.tex` as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"; dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi}}
\tikzset{external/force remake}

\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
CLFREQT 0.000000 0.500000 20 1.200000 5.883213
CLFREQT 5.883213 7.559856 20 1.000000 6.823011
CLFREQT 12.706224 14.382867 20 0.800000 7.633751
CLFREQT 20.339976 20.489868 20 1.000000 6.165892
CLFREQT 26.505868 26.655760 20 0.800000 7.780472
CLFREQT 34.286340 32.880138 20 0.600000 8.835256
CLFREQT 43.121595 38.181291 20 0.800000 9.379904
CLFREQT 52.501500 45.685215 20 1.000000 9.601305
CLFREQT 62.102805 55.286519 20 1.200000 9.431572
CLFREQT 71.534377 66.604406 20 1.000000 9.924455
CLFREQT 81.458832 76.528861 20 1.200000 9.469530
CLFREQT 90.928361 87.892297 20 1.000000 5.099208
CLFREQT 96.027570 92.991505 20 0.800000 8.763533
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{Fig.tikz}
\tikzsetnextfilename{Fig}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=north west,
        legend style={font=\small},
        xmode=linear,
        ymode=linear,
        axis x line*=bottom,
        axis y line*=left,
        tick label style={font=\small},
        grid=both,
        tick align=outside, 
        tickpos=left,
        xlabel=xlabel,
        ylabel=ylabel,
        xmin=0,xmax=100,
        ymin=0,ymax=100,
        width=0.45\textwidth,
        height=0.4\textwidth,
    ]
    \addplot+[mark=*,raw gnuplot,color=red] gnuplot {
        plot 'data.dat' using 2:3 w lp lw 3;
    };
    \addlegendentry{Legend};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[bth]
    \begin{tabular}{p{2.25in}}
        \scalebox{0.5}[0.5]{\includegraphics[]{Fig.tikz}}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\small This is the caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I compile the example.tex file through

```
latex -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape example.tex; dvips -o example.ps example.dvi; ps2pdf example.ps
```

The output errors are:

```
! LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in Fig.tikz (no BoundingBox).

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.61 ...ox{0.5}[0.5]{\includegraphics[]{Fig.tikz}}

<Fig.tikz> [1] (./example.aux) )
(see the transcript file for additional information)
Output written on example.dvi (1 page, 5416 bytes).
Transcript written on example.log.
This is dvips(k) 5.994 Copyright 2014 Radical Eye Software (www.radicaleye.com)
' TeX output 2014.10.02:1933' -> example.ps
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/dvips/base/color.pro>. 
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr9.pfb>
</usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
[1<./Fig.tikz>] 
Error: /undefined in \tikzsetnextfilename
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1900   1   3   %oparray_pop   1899   1   3   %oparray_pop   1883   1   3   %oparray_pop   1771   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:1168/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:86/200(L)--   --dict:181/300(L)--   --dict:66/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Last OS error: Invalid argument
Current file position is 57618
GPL Ghostscript 9.10: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

What is the cause to the error of "LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic"?

3. I have tried to get a compile using another MWE as shown below through  latex+dvips+ps2pdf.

   ```
   \documentclass{sig-alternate-10pt}

   \usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
   \usepackage{tikzscale}
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,calc,shapes,patterns}
   \usetikzlibrary{er}
   \usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.groupplots}

   \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
   \usepackage{currfile}
   \usepackage{lmodern}
   \usepackage{filecontents}

   \usetikzlibrary{spy}

   %\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}

   \usetikzlibrary{external}
   \tikzexternalize[prefix=figure-build/]
   %\tikzset{external/mode=list and make}
   %\tikzset{external/check=diff}

   %\tikzset{external/force remake}

   \pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

   \tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\string\def\string\myopts{\myopts}\texsource" && dvips -o "\image".ps "\image".dvi}}

   \usepackage{import}
   \usepackage[open-square,define-standard-theorems]{QED}
   \usepackage{listings}

   % available fonts (9/94) seem to be:
   % avantgarde bookman chancery lucida ncs palatino times
   \hyphenation{hy-phen-ation}

   % poor man's doublespacing (useful for less-than-exactly double spacing)
   % \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}

   %\include{prooftree}
   \includeonly{}

   \begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
   CLFREQT 0.000000 0.500000 20 1.200000 5.883213
   CLFREQT 5.883213 7.559856 20 1.000000 6.823011
   CLFREQT 12.706224 14.382867 20 0.800000 7.633751
   CLFREQT 20.339976 20.489868 20 1.000000 6.165892
   CLFREQT 26.505868 26.655760 20 0.800000 7.780472
   CLFREQT 34.286340 32.880138 20 0.600000 8.835256
   CLFREQT 43.121595 38.181291 20 0.800000 9.379904
   CLFREQT 52.501500 45.685215 20 1.000000 9.601305
   CLFREQT 62.102805 55.286519 20 1.200000 9.431572
   CLFREQT 71.534377 66.604406 20 1.000000 9.924455
   CLFREQT 81.458832 76.528861 20 1.200000 9.469530
   CLFREQT 90.928361 87.892297 20 1.000000 5.099208
   CLFREQT 96.027570 92.991505 20 0.800000 8.763533
   \end{filecontents}

   \begin{filecontents}{Fig.tikz}
   \tikzsetnextfilename{Fig}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[
           legend pos=north west,
           legend style={font=\small},
           xmode=linear,
           ymode=linear,
           axis x line*=bottom,
           axis y line*=left,
           tick label style={font=\small},
           grid=both,
           tick align=outside,
           tickpos=left,
           xlabel=xlabel,
           ylabel=ylabel,
           xmin=0,xmax=100,
           ymin=0,ymax=100,
           width=0.45\textwidth,
           height=0.4\textwidth,
       ]
       \addplot+[mark=*,raw gnuplot,color=red] gnuplot {
           plot 'data.dat' using 2:3 w lp lw 3;
       };
       \addlegendentry{Legend};
       \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{filecontents}

   \begin{document}

   %\include{exercises}
   %\baselineskip=0.22 in
   % \draftheader
   %\renewcommand{\theequation}{\Roman{section}.\Alph{equation}}
   \setcounter{Result}{0}

   %% this line is needed to work together with QED.sty
   \setcounter{equation}{0}

   \reversemarginpar

   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \setcounter{page}{1}

   \title{Dummy Title}

   %\date{}
   \maketitle

   \begin{figure}[bth]
       \begin{tabular}{p{2.25in}}
           \scalebox{0.5}[0.5]{\includegraphics[]{Fig.tikz}}
       \end{tabular}
       \caption{\small This is the caption.}
   \end{figure}

   \end{document}
   ```

I truly do not see a big difference of the 2 MWEs shown in 2. and 3. Why the MWE in 2. can not be compiled, but the MWE in 3. can be compiled?

Even after a successful compilation, the pdf file shown as attached is weird. A lot of white space is included in the figure. How to get rid of the white space?
[image]

Comment: It would probably be better to try to solve the non-embedding problem, since that ought not to happen, and stick with pdfTeX.